# How to detect exceptionally long file locks in linux?

Tags: linux, process, locking

I have a point of contention on my linux server.  One of a number of processes access a single file and lock the file at a random time for a considerable period (>60 seconds) which, in turn, causes other things to fail.

Is there a way to detect *how long* a file has been locked and by which process?

Comment: `lsof` will help you find which process locked the file, but doesn't give you how long since the process lock it.

Comment: Possibly [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)?

Comment: @masegaloeh Yes, I was aware of lsof for the second part of the question, hence the emphasis on "how long".

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew, possibly inotifywatch if used correctly.  I'll look at that and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the file `/proc/locks`. It shows the current file locks in the system. This not shows *how long a file has been locked*, but it shows **by which process**. Maybe you could detect when the lock is register in this file and measure the elapsed time. A sample is this:

```
cat /proc/locks 
1: POSIX  ADVISORY  WRITE 2245 08:06:1182714 1073741824 1073741824
2: POSIX  ADVISORY  WRITE 2245 08:06:1182714 1073741826 1073742335
3: POSIX  ADVISORY  WRITE 3058 08:06:10752740 0 0
4: POSIX  ADVISORY  WRITE 3058 08:06:10752739 0 0
5: POSIX  ADVISORY  WRITE 2421 08:06:10752766 0 EOF
6: POSIX  ADVISORY  WRITE 2421 08:06:11142048 0 EOF
7: POSIX  ADVISORY  WRITE 2421 08:06:9964366 1073741824 1073742335
8: POSIX  ADVISORY  WRITE 2421 08:06:11142040 0 EOF
```

Where the columns are:

- *First*: lock #.
- *Second*: lock type (POSIX if the lock was created with `fcntl` and `FLOCK` if created with `flock`.
- *Third*: lock mode (ADVISORY or MANDATORY)
- *Forth*: Lock type (WRITE or READ), corresponding to locks shared or exclusive.
- *Fifth*: PID of the process with the lock.
- *Sixth*: Three numbers separated by `:`  that identified the locked file.
- *Seventh*: Start byte of the lock.
- *Eighth:* End byte of the lock

Comment: +1 I was never really aware of `/proc/locks` - This actually solves another problem I have on some of my systems.

Comment: @ewwhite Make it a question!  I'd love to know how else you're using this. :-)

Comment: +1. Just FYI, "Sixth: Three numbers separated by : that identified the locked file." ; i think the 3 numbers that id the file are-   major#:minor#:inode#

Answer (score -2):

You can tell how old a lock file is by simply looking at the timestamp when it was created.  Similarly if you "cat logfile.name" it will very often have, as its sole contents, the process ID which created it.

Comment: Ahhhh.......You misread the question there is no lockfile.....what this user is asking concerns the lock function on a file that is open.

Comment: Indeed, @davidgo, there is no lockfile, the processes have a lock on a file.  e.g. int result = flock(fd, LOCK_SH);